# Getting JSON data

Tags: php, json

Im working with an api which stores data into a JSON file. This data is gathered from a form that the users fill in my website. The way its inserted goes as follow:

```
$pers_payload = array(
    'gender' => 'Unknown', //or Male / Female
    'first_name' => $_POST['billing_first_name'],
    'family_name'   => $_POST ['billing_last_name'],
    'email' => $_POST['billing_email'],
    'linked_as_contact_to_organization' => array(
        array(
            'organization_id' => $organization_id, // add the person as a contact to the newly created organization
            'work_email' => $_POST['billing_email'],
            'work_phone' => $_POST['billing_phone']
            )
        ),
    'visiting_address' => array(
        'country_code'          =>  'NL'
        ), // can be extented with other address data
    'postal_address' => array(
        'country_code'      =>  $_POST['billing_country'] 
    )   // can be extented with other address data
);
```

And then:

```
$person = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/crm/person',json_encode($pers_payload));
```

Now instead of post i want to get the data. I tried getting data like this:

```
$SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('GET','/crm/organization?q[name]=*my name*');
```

I dont know if this is the right way, well it didn't work so obviously its not.

Anyways what im trying to achieve is with PHP i want to gather the `name` value of an existing person. this data is stored in  `/api/v2/crm/person.json`

Api documentation (which i read but didn't understand to well) http://api.simplicate.nl/

Comment: Could you not just replace `$_POST` with `$_REQUEST` in your array constructor?

Comment: From what I can tell, the second request, meaning `$SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/crm/organization?q[name]=*my name*');` should be `GET` instead of `POST`. Other than that, I don't necessarily see anything wrong.

Comment: @Andrew sorry i tried get too, something went wrong with copy pasting. But i tried it already

Comment: Do you get any errors when making the call?

Comment: @Andrew nothing at all sadly.

Comment: Not even in the headers? That's odd to say the least. Would it be possible to post the full url? Unless it requires some sort of auth, in which case it's pointless. Try making a call using a simple cURL call, using a terminal of whatever, maybe you'll get some errors or something. It's very hard to tell what's wrong at the moment'.

Comment: @Andrew if it can post the data it should be able to get it. Also already tried to use curl, i got a bunch of results from it.

Comment: @Andrew /api/v2/crm/person?q[first_name]=Kevin this works in my browser and gives me json formated data. Is there a way to echo this data or output it somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while but i'm trying to answer all my open questions without an answer which i ended up solving on my own.

So for this.

You have to create a variable which makes the get request like this:

```
$test = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('GET','/crm/organization?q[name]=My name');
```

Now you can for example do a var_dump($test);

And as output you will get all the data inside

> /crm/organization?q[name]=My name